# PickerView select first row

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that pops up from the bottom of the IPhone's screen when a `UITextField` begins editing. When a row is selected my `UIPickerView` is dismissed.

But the problem is that don't manage to select the first row which is shown under the selection indicator.

Right now I can select all except the first row. So the `UIPickerView` never dismisses and I can't choose that value.

The only workaround I found is to scroll a bit the picker in order to still select the first row, so when I "release the touch" the first row is selected. But it's not a good workaround I need the same behavior I have with the other rows.

Thanks for your help as usual.

Wallou
Bye

Comment: other wise just put this [pickerview selectRow:firstRow incomponent:comp animated:yes] on loading of picker view .

Comment: yes i do.
i do this: [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];

but with or without i still can't select the first row like the others, just by touching it.

i tried [picker selectedRowInComponent:-1]; but of course it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way many apps do the trick is to add a button upon the picker to validate the selected item.